# Corda: Separate Attachments sending in a single transaction

Tags: corda

I'm having a three node network, where `Node 1` sends document as an attachment for a transaction to `Node 2` and `Node 3`. `Node 2` should also will send some attachments to `Node 3` . The first part of it, I have achieved it and published a state via flow. What i intend is to see all of this in a single transaction. can someone give me inputs on how to achieve this ?

Some additional Info: `Node 1` is also supposed to access the attachment sent by `Node 2` to `Node 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know what attachment hash to refer to in the first place. If the transaction is initiated by `Node 1`, it sounds like `Node 2` must have pre-uploaded the attachment and must know what the hash for it is (unless `Node 2` is able to figure out what the attachment must be based on the information contained in the state/transaction).

If you’re able to guarantee that, you can simply create a sub-flow that sends the `TransactionBuilder` generated by `Node 1` to `Node 2`, calls `addAttachment` and returns it back to `Node 1` for the transaction signing steps.

Comment: The thing is node 2 would decide what files it should attach after referencing to files send by node 1

Comment: That’s fine - the first attachment hash should be available in the `TransactionBuilder` (unless you mean the operator of `Node 2` needs to _manually_ reference the files before deciding what to attach). You can also send some arbitrary data as argument of the subflow to help `Node 2` decide what to do.

Comment: Then I don’t think you would be able to do it all in one transaction.

Comment: you might be able to do this in two steps (in the first steps the state - in an “incomplete”/“proposal” format is shared - along with the attachment from `Node 1` - with the rest of the nodes; in the second step the operators of `Node 2` can do the manual check and initiate a completion flow that adds the new attachment and marks the state as “completed”).